# How to pass a form as a parameter with events

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, events

My function currently accepts a form and saves it to a variable so that the form's events are caught in this module. Thing is, the form is strongly typed - every form needs its own function. It's a lot of duplicate code, so I tried making it generic by typing the variable as `Access.Form`, but the events stopped firing.

I think it might be because now the form is only defined at runtime. Whatever the reason, does anyone know if it's possible to pass a form anonymously without losing its events?

**Current code**

```
Private WithEvents frm As [Form_Create]

Public Sub Run(parentForm As [Form_Create])
    Set model = New mdlKita
    Set frm = parentForm
End Sub

// then I can do things like
Public Sub frm_OnCreate()
```

**Current code updated to be generic - events don't fire**

```
Private WithEvents frm As Access.Form

Public Sub Run(parentForm As Access.Form)
    Set model = New mdlKita
    Set frm = parentForm
End Sub

// this never fires
Public Sub frm_OnCreate()
```

***Inside the form in case someone's interested***

```
Private ctrl As ctrCreate

Private Sub btnContinue_Click()
    Set ctrl = New ctrCreate
    ctrl.Run Me
    RaiseEvent OnCreate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you miss to *Initialize* and *Terminate* a helper class - here for textboxes:

```vb
Option Explicit

' Helper class for form Palette for event handling of textboxes.
' 2017-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.0.0
' License: MIT.

' *

Private Const EventProcedure    As String = "[Event Procedure]"

Private WithEvents ClassTextBox As Access.TextBox


Public Sub Initialize(ByRef TextBox As Access.TextBox)

    Set ClassTextBox = TextBox
    
    ClassTextBox.OnClick = EventProcedure
    
End Sub


Public Sub Terminate()

    Set ClassTextBox = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub ClassTextBox_Click()

    ' Select full content.
    ClassTextBox.SelStart = 0
    ClassTextBox.SelLength = Len(ClassTextBox.Value)
    ' Display the clicked value.
    ClassTextBox.Parent!CopyClicked.Value = ClassTextBox.Value
    ' Copy the clicked value to the clipboard.
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

End Sub
```

- taken from my tiny project [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme)

Comment: What does `Private Const EventProcedure    As String = "[Event Procedure]"` do?

Comment: It marks the control to have an _OnClick_ event, and that event will be `[Event Procedure]` (as you otherwise would have to preset manually in the Property sheet). That procedure will be the one listed as `ClassTextBox_Click()`.